# Анимирование линии в tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

Идея в том, чтобы создать дождь. В классе "Капля" есть 2 метода: show(), который создаёт линию, и update(), который обновляет координаты, всё видно в коде:

```
    def show(self):
        c.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x, self.y+const, fill = "white")
    def update(self):
        self.y += self.yspeed

drops = [Raindrop() for i in range(101)]

def main():
    for i in range(len(drops)):
        drops[i].show()
        drops[i].update()
    root.after(30,main)

main()

root.mainloop()
```

Будет рисоваться линия, затем обновятся координаты и так циклично. Логично, что будет рисоваться новая линия по новым координатам, а старая линия со старыми координатами останется. Вот собственно и вопрос: как написать код так, чтобы этого избежать, т.е. когда рисуется новая линия по новым координатам, то старая стирается?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно не стирать/рисовать заново, а двигать старую линию. Пример кода:

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint


class Raindrop:
    def __init__(self, canvas, x, y, yspeed, length, color='blue'):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.yspeed = yspeed
        self.length = length
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.line = canvas.create_line(self.x, self.y, self.x, self.y+length, fill=color)

    def move(self):
        self.y += self.yspeed
        self.canvas.move(self.line, 0, self.yspeed)

        # При падении за нижний край холста передвигаем каплю выше верхнего края холста
        # Здесь размер холста жестко задан, но можно определять его размер и программно
        if self.y > 500:
            self.canvas.move(self.line, 0, -(500+self.length))
            self.y -= 500 + self.length


def redraw():
    for drop in drops:
        drop.move()

    root.after(10, redraw)


root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=500, height=500)
canvas.pack()

drops = [Raindrop(canvas, x=randint(0, 500), y=randint(0, 500), 
                  yspeed=randint(1, 3), length=randint(5, 20)) for i in range(101)]

redraw()

root.mainloop()
```

---

[image: Анимация]