# Отрисовка и обновление координат отрезков Canvas

Tags: python, tkinter

У меня есть 2 списка с координатами (x, y). Моя задача отрисовать эти отрезки и в дальнейшем обновлять их, но у меня всегда возникают проблемы. Я могу обновлять лишь одну линию, или создать все линии и не обновлять их. Подскажите, пожалуйста что мне стоит сделать.
Код который работает только с одной линией:

```
root = Tk()

root.overrideredirect(True)
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(screen_width, screen_height))
root.wm_attributes("-topmost", True)
# root.wm_attributes("-transparentcolor", "gray")

canvas = Canvas(root, bg='gray', width=1920, height=1080)
canvas.pack()


line = canvas.create_line(960, 1080, 0, 0, fill='purple', width=5)


def redraw_line(pos1, pos2):
    canvas.coords(line, (960, 1080, pos1, pos2))
    pos1 += 20
    pos2 += 10
    root.after(1, redraw_line, pos1, pos2)


redraw_line(0,0)

root.mainloop()
```

как я не пытался заставить код работать с более чем 1 линией, ничего не получалось.

Comment: Для начала выложить часть кода в котором проблемы, думаю это сможет помочь

Comment: сделайте класс линий с методом передвижения. и патом двигайте нужный объект через его метод

Comment: Отрезки раздельные или образуют ломаную линию (начало следующего отрезка совпадает с концом предыдущего)? Если раздельные, то должны храниться отдельно координаты начала/конца каждого отрезка. Каким образом должны меняться координаты (каждый отрезок движется целиком без изменения длины/поворота, или координаты начала/конца меняются независимо)?

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Анимирование линии в tkinter python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/934755)